# Ant+ connectivity

Tags: java, android

I would like to connect an ANT + compatible device to my Android phone but I can't find anything in the Android Dev doc, even in the "connectivity" folder. Does anybody know how I could do that?

Comment: Related: [What Android phones are ANT+ hardware enabled?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4644/3573) and more specifically: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/42428/3573

Comment: The Ant radio service in installed on my phone, so I guess it manages it (Galaxy S20+).

Comment: So you didn't find this: https://github.com/ant-wireless/ANT-Android-SDKs and the issues section seem relevant: https://github.com/ant-wireless/ANT-Android-SDKs/issues/14

Comment: Will have to dive into it but the link you mention seems promising.

Comment: Problem : the Ant lib is 5 years old! I'm stuck right at the beginning with an error caused by the use of "MODE_WORLD_READABLE", which is no longer available...

Comment: So the contents of the issue 14 thread wasn't enough?

Comment: According to the comment made on issue 14, the new version is likely to solve my problem. Unfortunately, as I am not very familiar with Github, I can't find a way to upload the pluginsampler directory (other than downloading each file individually, which would take a very long time). Can you tell me how I could do that in a simple way.

Comment: OK, I now have a functionnal app. Thanks for your help Chang!